# How to avoid downtime when updating a stage variable on a API gateway deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I have an API example_api currently deployed on stage DEV in AWS API gateway.

I want to update one of its stage variable and make sure the change is deployed. The API is provisioned by CloudFormation and the stage variables are mapped to template parameters.

I update the stack with boto3 and CloudFormation (using the UsePreviousTemplate flag) and provide the new value.

I then use boto3 to call create_deployment for example_api on DEV (to update already deployed example_api on DEV).

At this point, **my API becomes unavailable for around 15-20 seconds**. I keep receiving {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} responses.

I guess I am doing something wrong here. I do I avoid such a downtime and make sure the new API is available ASAP?

**Note:** my API is accessed through a custom domain name in API gateway. The base path is mapped to the DEV stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the cloud formation template had created the stage using the StageDescription property of the Deployment resource and I did not understand the deployment/stage relationship properly.

Resource Stage DEV was initially binded with Deployment Named000.

My first update_stack call used to update stage variable but also rebind the stage DEV to the initial deployment (Named000). Losing any changes applied since (any new routes).

I was able to update stage variables and properly deploy with no downtime by creating a Deployment resource and appending a timestamp to its name to make sure a new resource is created every time the stack is generated with Troposphere. Then updating the stack with new stage variables would keep stage binded with latest deployment and avoid introducing downtime.